# Swift 3 Core Data fetch issue

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

The function below is used to get data for tableview

```
func fetchProfiles() -> Array<User> {
    var users: Array<User> = []
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Profile> = Profile.fetchRequest()
    let fetchedData = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    if (!fetchedData.isEmpty) {
        print(fetchedData)
        for i in 0...fetchedData.count {
            var user: User = User()
            user.userName = fetchedData[i].profileName
            user.userSurname = fetchedData[i].profileSurname
            user.userPhoto = fetchedData[i].profilePhoto
            users.append(user)
        }
        return users
    }
    else {
        return users
    }
}
```

"User" is a simple struct. "Profile" is an entity in Core Data. I create an array of structs to use them for cells in table. Code has no errors(for xCode). When there is no fetched data, it skips appending array, but when there is some info, app crashes with error:

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element
>   type

Comment: Try replacing this line on fetch request, ***let fetchedData = try! context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [AnyObject]***

Comment: @Suresh xCode says: "Cannot convert value of type NSFetchRequest<Profile> to expected NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>"

Comment: Replace your let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Profile> = Profile.fetchRequest(); line with ***let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Profile")*** here, "Profile" should be your entity name, make sure you're passing it as String

Comment: @Suresh I tried this one before and it shows error: Cannot convert value of type "NSFetchRequest<>" to specified type "NSFetchRequest"
So my func written above is the only which do not show any error. But it crashes. Maybe it's smth with types

Comment: Okay, Keep your old snippet as it is, put a break point at ***if (!fetchedData.isEmpty) {*** this line, run the app, when debugger stopped at this line, start printing the 'fetchedData' by doing (po fetchedData) on the output console. Note the type of fetchedData while typing in the autocomplete, and share the printed fetchedData value. That would give some clue.

Answer (score 1):

For unknown reason, there were problems with auto generated headers of Core Data entities. I just deleted all files from folder:

> /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated

then cleaned my project with

> command+shift+k

checked my core data model for some possible issues and rebuilt the whole project. 
Magic.